# iOS symbolicate crash log only symbolicates a few lines

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, crash-reports, symbolicate

Hi I have this file symbolicated from:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3816a8bf 0x37cb61e5 0x3816a7b9 0x3816a7db 0x31e86747 0x31e87bb9 0x31dc0a45 0x31c4a227 0x31c44313 0x31c12921 0x31c123bf 0x31c11d2d 0x37e98df3 0x3813e553 0x3813e4f5 0x3813d343 0x380c04dd 0x380c03a5 0x31c43457 0x31c40743 0x9a0ad 0x9a000)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x307cb32c 0x307ba000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37c6cf54 0x37c1f000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37c65fe4 0x37c1f000 + 290788
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x306c7f64 0x306c1000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x306c5346 0x306c1000 + 17222
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cb62dc 0x37cad000 + 37596
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x306c53be 0x306c1000 + 17342
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x306c544a 0x306c1000 + 17482
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x306c681e 0x306c1000 + 22558
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cb622e 0x37cad000 + 37422
10  CoreFoundation                  0x380c053e 0x380b1000 + 62782
11  CoreFoundation                  0x380c039e 0x380b1000 + 62366
12  UIKit                           0x31c43450 0x31c0f000 + 214096
13  UIKit                           0x31c4073c 0x31c0f000 + 202556
14  HomeWizard                      0x0009a0a6 0x98000 + 8358
15  HomeWizard                      0x00099ff8 0x98000 + 8184
```

To this:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3816a8bf 0x380b1000 + 759999
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cb61e5 0x37cad000 + 37349
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3816a7b9 0x380b1000 + 759737
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3816a7db 0x380b1000 + 759771
4   UIKit                           0x31e86747 0x31c0f000 + 2586439
5   UIKit                           0x31e87bb9 0x31c0f000 + 2591673
6   UIKit                           0x31dc0a45 0x31c0f000 + 1776197
7   UIKit                           0x31c4a227 0x31c0f000 + 242215
8   UIKit                           0x31c44313 0x31c0f000 + 217875
9   UIKit                           0x31c12921 0x31c0f000 + 14625
10  UIKit                           0x31c123bf 0x31c0f000 + 13247
11  UIKit                           0x31c11d2d 0x31c0f000 + 11565
12  GraphicsServices                0x37e98df3 0x37e94000 + 19955
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3813e553 0x380b1000 + 578899
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3813e4f5 0x380b1000 + 578805
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3813d343 0x380b1000 + 574275
16  CoreFoundation                  0x380c04dd 0x380b1000 + 62685
17  CoreFoundation                  0x380c03a5 0x380b1000 + 62373
18  UIKit                           0x31c43457 0x31c0f000 + 214103
19  UIKit                           0x31c40743 0x31c0f000 + 202563
20  HomeWizard                      0x0009a0ad main (main.m:18)
21  HomeWizard                      0x0009a000 0x98000 + 8192
```

Has the process run correctly since I only see the main.m:18 the rest stays unknown.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Actually, I was not able to symbolicate iPhone crash logs since XCode 4.2/iOS 5.0. There are a lot of complains over the internet for XCode's symbolicating script.

Comment: Did you solve this? I think this is a bug in osx 10.7 related to spotlight. Basically you need to run mdimport . in the folders with the symbols. But where is the folder with IOS symbols??

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is that you don't have to corresponding iOS device symbols that the crash report happened on. The script searches for the UUID (found in the binary section) for the matching symbol file via spotlight. And if it can't find it, it will leave the line just as is.

Comment: And where should we look at to find those symbols?

Comment: You need to have a device with the specific iOS version and connect that to Xcode so it can import the symbols. The newer Xcode version all provide the symbols for the most recent iOS version, but otherwise there is currently no other way to get them.

Comment: I have all those symbols copied (I checked the folder) still not working

Comment: Could have a lot of reasons, e.g. those folders are not indexed by spotlight. There are multiple threads here giving hints how to get debug output and then provide solutions. Please post your issue as its own question including what you tried, and debug output of the symbolication script.